# Instagram API IP list

Tags: dns, ip, instagram, instagram-api

We have our project, which uses Instagram API, hosted on server, which has restricted access to the Internet. For Instagram API was made rule by IP address. But as Instagram has load balancer, this IP is always changing, so our project fails time to time due to firewall. 
Does anyone have list of api.instagram.com IPs? Or maybe know some other way to get it working.

Thanks

Comment: How about a proxy? Get a server with unrestricted internet and have it act as a bridge between your restricted servers and Instagram servers.

Comment: Yeah, It was one of ideas :)

Comment: i used all amazon aws ip ranges to fix same problem

Answer (score 1):

I believe Instagram being a Facebook product, the servers should be hosted in the same range that of the Facebook servers are.

Please checkout my github repo which keeps getting updated with the latest IP ranges of Facebook network

https://github.com/SecOps-Institute/FacebookIPLists

Let me know if that helps